# C# DocuSignJWT SDK - invalid_grant

Tags: docusignapi, jwt

I keep getting an "invalid_grant" error when I try to use the DocuSign sdk to generate a JWT user token, and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here...

```
public OAuthToken GetJwtToken(string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new ApiClient();

            var authToken = client.RequestJWTUserToken
            (
                IntegrationKey,
                userId,
                BaseUrl,
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateKey),
                1,
                new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" }
            );

            return authToken;
        }
        catch (ApiException e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

And the values:

```
<add key="IntegrationKey" value="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="PrivateKey" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n\xxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" />
<add key="BaseUrl" value="account-d.docusign.com" />
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the way the private key is coming in. I have it stored in the web config with \r\n for each new line, but if I try to just read it from the config file and pass it in, this line in the CreateRSAKeyFromPem() method throws a System.IO.IOException saying "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY not found" unless I do a '.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n")' on the private key string:

```
object result = pemReader.ReadObject();
```

I've looked at every thread I can find, copied the example code for this, and quadruple checked all of my values. I have no idea why this won't work.

Edit: I pasted the assertion string that the code is sending in the request into https://jwt.io/ and I was able to verify that the decoded data is correct and the signature is verified after pasting in my public and private keys. I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working after checking all of that.

Edit 2: This is how I'm storing my RSA private key:

```
<add key="DocuSign:PrivateKey" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\nxxxxxxx\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" />
```

and I'm retrieving it like this (System.IO throws this error if I try to grab the value without that Replace in there: "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY not found")

```
public static string PrivateKey { get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocuSign:PrivateKey"].Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n"); } }
```

Comment: how did you set your Integration Key in the DocuSign Admin in the sandbox?

Comment: RSA Private key has to be stored and provided exactly the way it is with all the end of lines etc.

Comment: @InbarGazit I didn't set it; It was made when I created the app. I just copied the value that it generated

As for the RSA Private key, I just removed the new lines in the string and replaced them with \r\n

Comment: ok, what I mean is the same place where you generated to the RSA Key. 
you also need to grant consent to the user. did you do that part?

Comment: I went through the Authorization Code Grant process, got consent from the user, and used that account id as the userId string above. My app is set to use Authorization Code Grant, so I shouldn't need to grant access manually, right? The link with the redirect uri that's part of the consent flow should be taking care of that.

Comment: I grabbed the assertion that's being generated by the code, and I was able to decrypt and verify the signature here: https://jwt.io/ , so I'm even more stumped now. Everything should be working, and I'm able to verify that the private key is able to verify the signature.

Comment: what userId and accountId are you using? did you ensure consent for that user?

Comment: I got consent by following [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent). I then got the user info by following [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant#step-3-retrieve-user-account-data) and tried both the "sub" user id and the account id in the jwt token to see if maybe I was using the wrong thing, and neither of them worked.

Comment: I don't think it's a consent issue since that should return {"error":"consent_required"}, and instead it's returning {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: ok, it can still be an issue with the private key. how did you store it?

Comment: I just added how I'm storing and retrieving it in my Edit 2 in the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to delete my RSA keypair for my app and generating a new one. The new key worked. I'm not sure why the old one didn't, but this resolved it at least.